# Java EE (Jakarta EE) сервера приложений, в чём разница?

Tags: java, java-ee

Я люблю и обожаю Java, использовал спринг, испрользовал много чего еще, но так вышло что Java EE (Jakarta EE) меня обошел стороной, но сейчас я решил попробовать.

И возник вопрос - в чем отличие серверов приложении, например WildFly от Glassfish и тд... (и соответственно какой выбрать)?

Спасибо.

Comment: "Пара базовых вопросов про Java EE (Jakarta EE)" - Переименуйте, вопрос, пожалуйста, или, если не получается изменить вопрос, на который можно дать однозначный ответ, то необходимо создать несколько вопросов. Я, офк, поставлю плюс, но на будущее: не надо в одном вопросе задавать овермного маленьких вопросиков!

Comment: Разделил на 3 вопроса, спасибо.

Comment: Грубо говоря, отличие такие же, как между BMW Series 7 и Mercedes S-Class - во множестве мелких и несущественных деталей.

Comment: Какой выбрать -это дело вкуса, с чем конкретно вам приятней работать. Если сервера полностью поддерживают спецификацию EE, то ваше приложение должно одинаково работать на любом из серверов. Рассчитывать на какие-то конкретные особенности того или иного сервера, наверное, не правильно.